# ¿Como girar un video en android studio?

Tags: java, android, video, studio

Al seguir la api camera de android studio al querer grabar un video y guardarlo, este de forma automatica se guarda girado hacia un lado, utilizo un MediaRecorder para enviar los datos a un directorio en el almacenamiento del celular, sin embargo en la api no menciona una manera de poder guardar el video en un grado en especifico, como logro hacer eso?

Comment: Pude resolver mi problema: al usar `MediaRecorder` esta tiene una función llamada `setOrientationHint()` en la cual se puede ajustar el ángulo de la orientación que se obtiene de la cámara ─en mi caso fue 90 grados─; esto se puede ver cuando se guarda el video de forma vertical. Aclaración: La razón por la cual no use un `intent` que me abra la grabadora del sistema fue porque necesito detectar los eventos que ocurren dentro como cuando el usuario hace click en grabar o detener.